# Change Culture in Web.Config Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

My configuration application collects the culture from the user. It is captured after the user makes a selection.

`CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(selectedCulture);`

Now, I need to update the Web.config of the main application. Currently, it defaults to `en-us`:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="en-us" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Here is what I have managed so far, with the part I am failing to figure out highlighted with a TODO.

```
XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
config.Load("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyProject\\web.config");
// TODO - Modify the globalization culture
config.Save("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyProject\\web.config");
```

I see methods for grabbing elements by ID, but my globalization doesn't have an ID. When i tried to give it an ID, I got `The "id" attribute is not allowed.` What method will manipulate  the globalization element in a way that allows me to change the culture? Do I need to use a different structure to load the document?

Comment: You can use an Xpath expression to locate the element you want to update.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this via the web.config? Why not a cookie and setting Thread.CurrentCulture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Xpath to find the element and then update the data:

```
XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
config.Load("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyProject\\web.config");

var node = config.SelectNodes("system.web/globalization")[0];
node.Attributes["culture"].Value = "new value";

config.Save("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyProject\\web.config");
```

Comment: I had to use config.SelectNodes("configuration/system.web/globalization")[0];, but otherwise this works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that: if you modify your web.config ASP.NET will restart your application.

Instead of that, you can set your globalization in web.config like:

`<system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="auto" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    ...
</system.web>`

Then, you can use, as @luke-mcgregor said, `Thread.CurrentCulture` to retrieve the user's culture